# java/spring boot connect to container and run bash command

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have docker instance which has three containers: one for spring boot, one for postgres, one for nginx. What i'm trying to do is do an pg_dump on button click from an html page and send the pg_dump back to the user as some file.

My understanding is that to run pg_dump it has to be on the postgres server, but I can't figure it out. How would I, from a spring boot java class, connect to the postgres container, run the pg_dump, and get that back to the springboot container to give to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can run [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html) from anywhere that can connect to the database; it takes the usual connection parameters as command-line options or environment variables.  If you're running both parts in a Compose setup, for example, this could look like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      PGHOST: db
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

You'd have to install the PostgreSQL client tools in your application's Dockerfile.

```sh
FROM openjdk:11
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      postgresql-client
WORKDIR /app
COPY myapp.jar .
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/myapp.jar"]
```

Your application can then run `pg_dump` as an ordinary subprocess; you don't need anything Docker-specific to make the connection.  You could run this same setup in a non-Docker development environment or under alternate container orchestrators like Kubernetes.

There are both additional complexities and significant security issues with getting access to the Docker socket.  Your application would need to build in a Docker SDK, and be given access to the Docker socket on the host.  Once it has that socket, it's very easy to use it to root the entire host.  You don't need that privilege just to make queries against a database.